# Javascript NaN Error on Big Mac Alert

Tags: javascript

Probably something dumb I am doing here but getting an alert of `NaN` after I hit Big Mac.

```js
var BigMac = {
  name: "Big Mac",
  price: 5.40,
  quantity: 0
};
var total = 0;
alert(total);

function Buy(item) {
  var price = item.price;
  var total = total + item.price;
  alert(total);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="Buy(BigMac);">Big Mac</a>
```

Comment: `var total = total + item.price;`: `total` is `undefined` at that point, in that scope. Just remove the `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Xufox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox) pointed out in the comments above:

> `var total = total + item.price;`
>
> `total` is `undefined` at that point, in that scope. Just remove the `var`.

Also, instead of `total = total + item.price` you can use `total += item.price` as shorthand.

```js
var BigMac = {
  name: "Big Mac",
  price: 5.40,
  quantity: 0
}

var total = 0

console.log(total)

function Buy(item) {
  total += item.price
  console.log(total)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="Buy(BigMac)">Big Mac</a>
```